How to correctly stream videos from a S3 bucket using HLS format
I am totally confused about a video streaming app I have been making for fun.
I have:

Node JS server
Minio Buckets
Javascript Client
HLS ()H.264 and MP4 version of uploading and streaming.

Should I be:

Streaming the video from bucket to client using the bucket URL and letting it handle chunks of data sent back? Or,
Streaming from my bucket to my server and then to my frontend with the server managing sending back chunks? The server sends back one .m3u8 file and then sends the rest as .ts chunks.

My server originally sent the mp4 files in chunks based on the range in headers. Now the .m3u8 files are already broken down into chunks of .ts.
I found someone online who lets you see the frontend code and I can tell that the client makes one request for a .m3u8 file and then in the network tab a series of .ts chunks are being sent back as well. So I can't tell what the server is doing to make these chunks.
I might also be a little confused about how buckets really work but thats a different problem.
The frontend code is very basic React setup and this is all that's needed to call a video:
const playerRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

const [hlsUrl, setHlsUrl] = useState(
    'https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8'
);

return (
    <ReactHlsPlayer
      playerRef={playerRef}
      src={hlsUrl}
      autoPlay={true}
      controls={false}
      width='60%'
      height='auto'
    />
)

I tried sending it through the same system to send back an mp4 but it sent the m3u8 and then couldn't send the .ts files
If it's not too clear, I'm badly trying to ask how do people set up a server to work with streaming, hls and buckets all in one?
I don't need code just guidance.

"But it sent the m3u8 and then couldn't send the .ts files" Is the problem fixed now? Your link is working fine to show Big Buck Bunny (so the TS files are definitely coming through okay). Tested: https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8

The primary purpose of HLS is that it allows you to use regular web servers as live streaming servers.
Media is broken up into segments.  The client requests a playlist (M3U8 format) which points it at the media segments (MP4/ISOBMFF or TS).
The client downloads the playlist to see what media segments it needs.  It then downloads those segments and reassembles them into a stream for playback.
Because the whole protocol revolves around files, nothing special is needed of the web server, other than to serve these files.  Therefore, an S3-compatible bucket becomes a quick and dirty streaming server.  You just upload the playlist and segments to it, and the clients can downloads from it.  Then as you scale up, you can drop any normal HTTP-based CDN in front of that bucket to easily relay our segments to the edge efficiently.

Should I be:

Streaming the video from bucket to client using the bucket URL and letting it handle chunks of data sent back? Or,


Yes.  Push your segment files to the bucket, and let the clients connect directly to the bucket.  Do not involve your Node.js application server in this side, there's no need for it.
I do want to address something else though from your question that isn't quite clear.

My server originally sent the mp4 files in chunks based on the range in headers.

This is even better than your HLS version!  Why wouldn't you do this?
Your media is already pre-recorded.  You're not offering multiple layers of encoding or anything like that.  Therefore you have zero benefit to use HLS instead of just streaming the MP4 file.  In fact, because you're converting it to HLS, you're actually hurting your compatibility a bit.
S3 can already handle ranged requests.  Browser clients already know how to request the ranges you need.  You don't need to convert to HLS.  Just put the file on the server and be done with it!
If you are having trouble streaming your original MP4s, you might just need to adjust the location of the moov atom:
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -c copy -movflags faststart optimized.mp4

